# Why Spring isn't delegate request to controller sometimes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, filter

I've got an application with Spring 4 and Spring security 3 based on Jetty.

Only one user can be signing in with the same credentials. If someone will sign in with same username, previous user will be automatically logged out. It's all working fine if app doing it by itself, but sometimes you have a delay so you need to do any request to server for logging out.

However, if I'll try to refresh page while I'm signing in with two different browsers, I'll have only 200 OK response without any information.
After next refresh only I'll have valid response with information inside.

I've got few filters in `security.xml`

```
<http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>
    <custom-filter ref="responseFilter" position="FIRST"/>
    <custom-filter ref="httpRequestSessionIdFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <custom-filter ref="corsFilter" position="HEADERS_FILTER"/>
    <custom-filter ref="preLogoutFilter" before="LOGOUT_FILTER"/>
```

I think trouble somewhere after `ResponseFilter`. In this situation other custom filters aren't invoked:

```
public final class ResponseFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    ResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

    chain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);
    String responseContent = new String(responseWrapper.getDataStream());
```

I tried to invoke `chain.doFilter` again if response data was empty and it works, but response status and data were split into two different JSONs.

Why this happens and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Have you tried to enable DEBUG log level and look into it?

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov , thanks for advice, absolutely forgot about it.

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov, Filtering stopped at 3rd of 17 filters. Last filter is ConcurrentSessionFilter then SecurityContextLogoutHandler says that session isn't valid

Comment: Well, then gear up with a Debugger, put a breakpoint inside ConcurrentSessionFilter and have fun :)